# Odd behavior with mongodb find

Tags: mongodb

In my DB when I execute db.markers.find() I have this result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518134733198c6952f000000"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -48.8397216796875, -19.68656825792867 ] }, "m_info" : { "category" : "14", "sub_category" : "156", "description" : "Teste" }, "user_info" : { "email" : "user@gmail.com", "name" : "John Doe" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518192d13198c69e3c000000"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -44.52420382953613, -17.586578222234177 ] }, "marker_info" : { "category" : "9", "sub_category" : "118", "description" : "I'm working with TI." }, "user_info" : { "email" : "user2@gmail.com", "name" : "John Doe2" } }
```

but when I try something like db.markers.find({ user_info : { email : 'user@gmail.com' }}) it returns no results
Why is this not working?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are looking for all documents where user_info object is *exactly* `{ email : 'user@gmail.com' }`

If you want to match a document which happens to have email as 'user@gmail.com" inside of user_info regardless of the rest of the subdocument use [the dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```
db.markers.find({ "user_info.email" : "user@gmail.com })
```